# SQL Query to perform division

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to perform SQL division using Oracle, such that, all `User_ID` that have teaches SAME classes as a specific ID, should be returned.

Table structures of both tables, I'm working with:

```
HUMAN(id, first, last)
INSTRUCTOR(human_id, location) -- PK(id, location)
CLASS(instructor_id, class_code, class_num) -- PK(instructor_id, class_code, class_num)
```

Query I'm currently working with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT instructor_id, class_code, class_num
FROM CLASS
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  (SELECT instructor_id, class_code, class_num FROM CLASS)
  MINUS
  (SELECT instructor_id, class_code, class_num
  FROM CLASS
  WHERE instructor_id =
  (SELECT HUMAN.id
  FROM HUMAN
  WHERE first = 'Foo'
  AND last = 'Bar')))
```

Sample data

```
HUMAN  
id   first   last
 1   foo     bar
 2   John    Doe

INSTRUCTOR  
human_id   location   
      1    US
      2    CA

CLASS
instructor_id   class_code    class_num
     1             CS            999
     1             MA            111
     1             DE            222
     2             CS            999
     2             MA            111
     2             DE            222
     3             CS            999
     4             CS            999
```

The query should return `instructor_id 2`, since it is the only one that instructs same classes as `instructor_id 1`

The query I have returns no row, despite inserting data to match this scenario.

Comment: What does "same class" mean  -  same class code or same class num, or both? In your sample, there is a one-to-one relationship between the two columns, but presumably in your real-life data that's not the case (perhaps class_num reflects both the class_code and the semester? or the location? - otherwise why have both?)

Comment: Same class mean,  both class_code and class_num

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT instructor_id, class_code, class_num
 FROM CLASS
WHERE class_num IN (SELECT class_num from CLASS WHERE instructor_id = (SELECT HUMAN.id FROM HUMAN  WHERE first = 'Foo'  AND last = 'Bar'))
```

This will return all the instructors (including Foo Bar) which give the same class as Foo Bar.

If you want to exclude Foo Bar, just add another WHERE class (instructor_id != (SELECT HUMAN.id FROM HUMAN  WHERE first = 'Foo'  AND last = 'Bar'))

Comment: This query return all `instructor_id` that instructs at least one of the classes instructed by `foo bar`

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways:

```
with t as (
  select distinct instructor_id id, class_num cn
    from class
   where instructor_id = (select id from human
                           where first = 'foo' and last = 'bar'))
select c.instructor_id as id, max(h.first||' '||h.last) as name
  from class c
  join human h on c.instructor_id = h.id
  join t on t.cn = c.class_num and c.instructor_id <> t.id
  group by instructor_id
  having count(distinct class_num) = (select count(1) from t)
```

Test data and output:

```
create table HUMAN  (id number(3), first varchar2(5), last varchar2(5));
insert into human values (1, 'foo', 'bar');
insert into human values (2, 'John', 'Doe');

create table INSTRUCTOR (human_id number(3), location varchar2(3));
insert into instructor values (1, 'US');
insert into instructor values (2, 'CA');

create table CLASS (instructor_id number(3), class_code varchar2(3), class_num number(4));
insert into class values (1, 'CS', 999 );
insert into class values (1, 'MA', 111 );
insert into class values (1, 'DE', 222 );
insert into class values (2, 'CS', 999 );
insert into class values (2, 'MA', 111 );
insert into class values (2, 'DE', 222 );
insert into class values (3, 'CS', 999 );
insert into class values (4, 'CS', 999 );
```

Output:

```
  ID NAME
---- -----------
   2 John Doe
```

Comment: If I alter one class instructed by John Doe, which means, it no longer matches exactly ALL classes instructed by Foo Bar, I still get John Doe, it should return empty row.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM instructor i
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT *
             FROM class c
            WHERE c.instructor_id = i.human_id
           MINUS
           SELECT *
             FROM class c
            WHERE instructor_id = (SELECT human.id
                                     FROM human
                                    WHERE FIRST = 'Foo' AND LAST = 'Bar'));
```